# Hook for Decrypting Passwords with Spring Cloud Connectors

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

We have an application that is deployed into CloudFoundry/Bluemix.  The application reads its database connections from the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.  The db password stored in the environment variable is encrypted and we decrypt it when the application boots up.

We are looking at [Spring Cloud Service Connectors](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server_2).  Do the cloud connectors provide any hook, so that we can decrypt the password from VCAP_SERVICES before the DataSource instance is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? Where does the app get its decryption key from? If it's hard-coded in the app, that's an antipattern that will make it hard to rotate the key. If it's through an environment variable, then it's no more secure than storing the database credentials unencrypted as services in Cloud Foundry - services in CF are nothing more than domain-specific groups of environment variables. I can't see that encrypting them adds any security.

To answer the question: Not out-of-the-box, but you could probably intercept the flow of Spring components that act on the environment variables that Cloud Foundry provides to your app.

The abstract class that creates `ServiceInfo` instances is [CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator.java). You could look at maybe providing a custom implementation of this? There is a [blog post describing how Spring Cloud Connectors works](https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/05/extending-spring-cloud). You might be able to extend [CloudFoundryConnector](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/cloudfoundry/CloudFoundryConnector.java#L65) too.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. The key is currently hard coded in the app, so it's not easy to rotate. We are forbidden from storing unencrypted passwords in our CF spaces to prevent anyone with access to the space from stealing credentials. I work for a large financial institution and this is a symptom of an organization problem ;).

Comment: Ha, definitely sounds like an organisation problem! We've worked with some global banks and wealth management firms, so we know your pain. It's pointing out that anyone who can see env vars in CF can probably also run `cf files` against your app, and thus download the .jar and view the strings there-in.

Comment: Agreed.  This is more an obfuscation mechanism.  If someone on the production support team had the know-how, they could reverse engineer the password.  Is there a proper way to solve this problem?